# Unexpected provisioning problem in iPhone

Tags: iphone, provisioning

Accidentally while running a downloaded application in order to run it on device, I selected my current working provisioning profile along with the associated app Id, as a result of which not only did that application didn't run on device [obviously], but my current application has started displaying that application's splashscreen first followed by my application.

I am confused about what to do now, as I already created new app Id with new provisioning profile, cleaned the build several times, but it's still showing me that application's splashscreen prior to my application.

Comment: Have you completely removed both applications and the provisioning profiles on the device, before running your app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps

- remove the downloaded and your application from the Homescreen
- restart the device
- rebuild and install the app on the device